# fatal: '$GIT_DIR' too big when using CMake's FetchContent feature

Tags: git, cmake

I'm using CMake's FetchContent feature to fetch the [esp-azure](https://github.com/espressif/esp-azure) repo. While doing so I got the following:

```
Cloning into 'C:/code/my-repo/build/_deps/espazure-src/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/deps/utpm/deps/c-utility/deps/umock-c/deps/ctest/deps/azure-macro-utils-c'...
fatal: '$GIT_DIR' too big
fatal: clone of 'https://github.com/Azure/azure-macro-utils-c.git' into submodule path 'C:/code/my-repo/build/_deps/espazure-src/azure-iot-sdk-c/provisioning_client/deps/utpm/deps/c-utility/deps/umock-c/deps/ctest/deps/azure-macro-utils-c' failed
Failed to clone 'deps/azure-macro-utils-c'. Retry scheduled
```

I tried defining `git config core.longpaths true` but that didn't help. My guess is that the cloned repositories have their own git configs and so the parameter is overwritten.

How can I tackle this?

Comment: Looks like you are exceeding the max path handled by `git`.  Try setting `FetchContent` `SOURCE_DIR` parameter to clone into a location with a smaller absolute path.

Comment: @fdk1342 I'm sure sure that'll help as the problem is less with the path to my repo and more with the path to the dependency repo. I'm looking for a more general solution, as reallocation `SOURCE_DIR` has other meanings as well.

Comment: The links I followed on your git error referred to this line of code as being the error.  It seems that you are exceeding the max path that git will use.  Maybe you can find a workaround.https://github.com/git/git/blob/54e85e7af1ac9e9a92888060d6811ae767fea1bc/setup.c#L812

Comment: @fdk1342 Thanks, I tried `set PATH_MAX=4096` but that didn't help as well. I wonder what can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this error so I tried with the command
`git clone <git-repo> <short-directory-name>`

And this worked for me.

Giving shorter directory name to the cloned location helped